# Is every power of a group element also contained in the group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If we know that $a$ is in a group, then any power of $a$ would also be in the group because it is closed under the group operation, right?

Comment: Yep, that's right (including the case of negative exponents)

Comment: You're correct. Moreover, if the group is of finite order, there must exist $i$ and $j$ such that, at some point, $a^i = a^j$. More info [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/908212/for-every-element-of-a-finite-group-there-are-two-distinct-exponents-that-produ)

Comment: Where else would it be?

Comment: Yes, for any integer power.

Answer (score 0):

A binary operation on a set $S$ is a function $f$ with domain $S\times S$ and co-domain $S$. This means **any** combination of the group's operation stays in the group.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a formal proof, $a=a^1$ is in the group by your hypothesis, and assuming that $a^{i-1}$ is in the group it follows that $a^i = a a^{i-1}$ is in the group. So by induction, $a^n$ is in the group for all $n$.